Assimp load original vertex positions and face data
for an algorithm that I'm writing I need to load model files, so I tried using assimp today, however after loading a simple cube with assimp, it results in more vertices in the assimp datastructure than the original file had, and a lot of them are just duplicates.
For my algorithm I need the original vertices and indices, because I need to find triangles that share the same edge, thus there can't be duplicate vertices.
Is there any way to load the original vertices and indices using assimp, or is there another library that does that?

The vertices are optimized for rendering. You can check https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/633306-assimp-number-of-vertices/ to get a better understanding.
